# C - msgrcv adds characters to message received, very strange

Tags: c, message-queue

so my `msgrcv()` function call works great, but it adds on characters to what is received from the other process.

Where the sender process sends *hello*, the receiver process receives *hello@\n* or *hello\n@* or *hello@*,because it prints different things randomly, this is very hard to cheat fix with some character pruning.

Code:

```
    if (msgrcv(clientQueueID, &msg, sizeof(msg.data), 0, 0) == -1)
    {
        // No message received from client
    }
    else
    { .........
```

In this case, printing msg.data shows that it has extra characters attached.

This is how I'm printing:

```
printf("RECEIVED MESSAGE LENGTH %d: '%s'\n", (int)strlen(msg.data), msg.data);
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I knew this was a strange issue...Turns out it's a problem with my client. I had a simple little function that scanned for '\n' and replaced it with '\0' to "remove" it so the new line wouldn't be sent.

Anyway, the solution was to just not remove the new line from the client. Somehow the server is reading everything correctly now, new line and all. Hope that helps somebody down the line.